# How to check if an AVIF still image has been lossless encoded

Tags: image-processing, lossless, heif, avif

I have an avif still image file that I know has been lossless encoded.

I'm trying to find a command line tool (or other way) that allow me to check that the file has been lossless encoded (instead of lossy).

I have tried with `heif-info` (from `libheif`) and `magick identify` but none of the information showed help me to know if the image has been lossless encoded or not.

Is there any command tool to check if an avif file has been lossless encoded?

Comment: For checking... Can you provide downloadable links of two AVIF copies of same image, where one copy is "lossless encoded" and the other copy is not (is it "lossy" instead?).